# minecraft says diconnected upon trying to connect to multyplayer

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

air m2 and when i try to connect to a multiplayer server on T launcher if just says disconnected . does it have to do any thing with my network or its just mac security please let me know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i can't connect to a server ex herobrine.org

Comment: How are you running the game? Are you using the native launcher from Minecraft.net?

Comment: nope i am using tlauncher